# How do I operate the control buttons on my Yuraku 23" monitor?

Tags: display

I have owned, and been eminently satisfied with, my Yuraku 23" monitor for a couple of years now; however, I did not receive a users manual when I bought it.

As I would like to increase the volume, how do I operate the little "control" buttons at the bottom of my screen?

Answer (score 0):

Download the manual from [Yuraku support](http://www.yuraku.com.sg/www.yuraku.com.sg/download.html). You'll need to know the model number (which will be on it somewhere, perhaps at the back).

*It would have been better to include the model number in your question.*